# Installing SQL Server and .NET Framework from a visual studio setup project

Tags: c#, .net, setup-deployment

I have to do  four things install .net framework 3.5 ,install SQL Server 2005 and run my sql script on the server and create the database and install my application how to do it in a single setup project using visual studio 2005/2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSIS instead of the Visual Studio installer project:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

It's much more powerful, but still pretty straightforward to use.  Also there's lots of sample code for common tasks like installing .NET or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install SQL Server from a Visual Studio setup project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to write an installer yourself or get an installer that you can attach other installers to it. Not sure why you would want to install sqlserver on a client's machine. Why not go with SQLLite or something that can be installed easily and have your database deployed without running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The framework can't be installed from within an MSI setup project. you can specify that it is a prerequisite but can only hope that the use will go through with the installation. If you are running a simple application you might get away with embedding the framework basic files in to your installation package.

Then comes SQL2005. If you can settle with SQL2005 express then the proper DLLs will be added to your project and no installation needs to be done. If you do need a standard edition then you can execute the SQL installation with predefined flags.

Creating a database is a little more tricky as the user should specify the database location and have the SQL server have privileges on that folder. I would strongly recommend NOT to create the database & run the scripts in the setup project but do it as a wizard the first time the program is executed.

The more you add up to the setup project the harder it will be to roll-back everything if something goes wrong in the installation.

Gilad.

Comment: Are you sure about this? This article seems to point in another direction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx#redist

Answer (score 0):

this article can also be helpfull for installing sql server

http://www.csharpnedir.com/articles/read/?id=1032&filter=unedited&title=SETUP%20PROJES%C4%B0%20%C4%B0%C3%87ER%C4%B0S%C4%B0NDE%20SQL%20SERVER%20KURMAK